# Error on install SSL in EC2 with Let's Encrypt

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm pretty new on aws ec2, I'm trying to get a free ssl with Let's Encrypt. I've watched a video in youtube to learn it, but I have a problem, my terminal says *sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found*, always when I type the command  *add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot*
I'm using Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM), is it the problem? If it is the problem, how can I fix it? Which command I need to use to install?

Comment: I watched a video that the person uses an Ubuntu, maybe the command is different, so which one should I use?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sMrf9LiO00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt` is the package manager for Debian-based Linux distros. Amazon Linux is CentOS/RHEL-based distro, it uses `yum` as package manager.

To install Let's Encrypt SSL certificate on Amazon Linux you can follow the step-by-step tutorial by AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#letsencrypt

You will have to import EPEL repository from Fedora (instead of PPA), then install Certbot from Let's Encrypt and issue an SSL certificate using Certbot.

Minimal command set for Amazon Linux:

```
sudo wget -r --no-parent -A 'epel-release-*.rpm' http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/
sudo rpm -Uvh dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-*.rpm
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel*
sudo yum install -y certbot python2-certbot-apache
sudo certbot
```

Comment: I followed all your steps, this seems to be useful, however, I was not successful, maybe this is due to the fact that I don't have my own domain www.example.com, and I'm using the Amazon standard, am I right about that? The most correct thing to do then is to use my own domain to obtain the ssl certificate?